# Occasional Severe SQL Slowdowns

Tags: sql-server

Loading a page in a web app that makes local database calls generally takes 10-15 seconds for a given query. Loading the exact same page occasionally takes ~10-15 times as long, and I've traced the additional page load time back to increased SQL query execution time. I'm a novice when it comes to SQL so beyond checking my CPU and memory (I'm never over 50% on either), I don't know where to start.

I've tried searching for similar problems/solutions, but have generally only found references to people being out of memory, or instructions specifically based on optimizing a stored procedure that is *always* running slowly. Neither of these seem to address my issue, which is that running the exact same queries occasionally takes 10-15 times longer than when I run them at different times. Unfortunately, I haven't been able to find any immediate work-arounds such as restarting my computer.

This has happened three times over the last ~2 weeks. One moment it is working fine, the next, it's taking 10 times as long. Eventually, it gets back to normal - both times I left my computer overnight/over the weekend without powering down and returned to fast load times when I came back in and tried again. I did not exit out of any applications or explicitly alter the state of my system in either case.

I'm running SQL Server 2012 on Windows 8, if that is of any importance. I'm at a loss as to why this is happening, so any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks, David

**Edit: answered by a former co-worker of mine:**

running this query: dbcc freeproccache

fixed it. Explained here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174283.aspx

quick explanation of his was, "SQL figures out a query plan when a proc is first executed. If the first execution is atypical, it can cause the storage of a bad plan."

Thanks to everyone who responded.

Comment: SQL Profiler is your friend: you can start it, filter on specific events (otherwise profiler itself causes not insubstantial overhead) and click around your site: you then look at the profiler output to identify any suspect SQL.

Comment: I would look at other processes that are blocking the call to the page.

Comment: @David, if your edit fixed the problem then you should make an answer and put the solution in it and accept your own answer so others with this problem can see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

answered by a former co-worker of mine:

running this query: dbcc freeproccache

fixed it. Explained here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174283.aspx

quick explanation of his was, "SQL figures out a query plan when a proc is first executed. If the first execution is atypical, it can cause the storage of a bad plan."

Thanks to everyone who responded.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an sql-server expert by any means but I've had to debug a couple of situations like this as well.

Using the profiler is what worked best for me.  This is the link that I started with, it discusses how to monitor your db with the profiler.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa173918(v=sql.80).aspx

In my case the source of the slow down was one C# clean up process that hammered the db in a tight loop trying to read, then sanitize, and then write back the data to the db, which didn't let other processes have much room for executing during the 2 minutes it was running.

The profiler detected this right away

Comment: Thanks for your response. My boss and I have looked over the profiler log and haven't noticed anything like what you're describing. What did the events you're describing look like in the profiler?

Comment: @David, well for our scenario since it was one stored procedure continually being called we immediately saw it by logging and watching the SP:Staring and SP:Completed events happened every few milliseconds.

Comment: Thanks, I got it fixed. Turned out the problem was something else (in my edit above). I appreciate the response nonetheless!